# Separating posts in a newsfeed using CSS/BootStrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to render a newsfeed, similar to that of FB on a Rails application I'm working on. Unfortunately, I'm not the greatest when it comes to CSS and I'm having some issues trying to display different posts. This issue occurs whether I'm using BootStrap or plain CSS. I do believe it's something to do with the loop that is created by `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` Currently, whenever a new post is made, it wraps inside the previous post; thus the more posts that are made, the thicker the border gets.

Image: [image: Newsfeed]

```
<% if @posts.any? %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="well">
  <a href="/users/<%= post.user.id %>/show"><%= post.user.first_name %> <%= post.user.last_name %></a><br>
  <% if !post.image.exists? %>
    <h2> <%= post.text %> </h2>
  <% else %>
    <h2> <%= link_to post.text, post_path(post) %> </h2>
    <%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
      <p><%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% if @user %>
    <% if current_user.voted_up_on?(post) %>
      <%= link_to "Like", dislike_post_path(post), method: :put %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(post), method: :put %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= "Likes: #{post.get_upvotes.size}" %>
<% if post.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
<div id='comments_div' class="comments-index">
  <%= render post.comments %>
</div>
<% if current_user %>
  <%= form_for [post, post.comments.new ], remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area :text, placeholder: 'Add a comment' %>
   <%= f.submit 'Comment' %>
  <% end %>
<% else%>
  <p>You need to <%= link_to "sign in", new_user_session_path %> to comment</p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
No posts have been added!
<% end %>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: OK, please take a look at the new image -- hopefully that will make the issue slightly more obvious. Additionally, I've removed all the dead tags and replaced them with just one: BootStrap's 'well' class. So, there you have it. All the information you need is within the code above.

Comment: Provide full HTML + CSS code, and post the rendered HTML here.

Comment: There really isn't anything inside the CSS files that will help you. Imagine that there is just one class, <div class="newsfeed">, which contains a simple border and centred text. That's it. I just need to know how to separate the posts, so that they don't wrap inside of each other.

Comment: what do you mean by wraps within the previous posts ? Can you tell us more what is getting wrapped & how does it appear after wrapping ?

Comment: Your loops are all over the place. The `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` loop is closing at the very beginning before `<div class="post-features">` itself. Even the `<div>` are not properly closed. Check it well using some indentation tool

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. There is an image in the OP -- unsure if you can see it though. Basically, every time a new post gets made, a new border is also created; however, the new post will then sit inside of the of the old one, and create a new border which is 'thicker' than the previous.

Comment: OK, there are currently lots of <div> tags thrown in there, however most of them aren't in use and are there purely as placeholders. Please note, that even with just one <div class> tag opening at the beginning, and closing at the end, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Wait, you said that the `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` loop closes at the beginning? This is not true -- it loops through the whole file, hence why every posts contains the option to like, edit and delete.

Comment: But what about the most important one, your `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` ? Thats ending after the `<%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>` which means only your User ID & image is getting iterated for all (not the others).

Comment: I don't think so .. the `<% end %>` just before the closing div of `posts-index`. What is that ? There are 2 `<% end %>` there, don't think you need them both

Comment: The first end, ends the if statement; the second end, ends the second do loop. Neither of them end the @posts.each loop.

Comment: Ok much better, now put your last `</div>`(of the well class) just before the last second `<% end %>`(of the `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` loop). So at the end of your code it should be `<% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>` This should fix

Answer (score 1):

from your description it sounds as though an html element is not being properly closed. Run the page source through an html validator and that could show you the problem.

If you don't want to take a structured problem solving approach, try adding another `</div>` to the end of your posts-index container.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is very simple, just that its not clear due to poor indendation.

A simple way to explain what you did is:

```
<-- if (start) -->
  <-- do (start) -->
    <-- post (start) -->

    (post is not ending here, hence it breaks the layout)
  <-- do (end) -->
<-- if (end) -->
<-- post (end) -->
```

Mistake in the above should be simple to understand so if you move your last `</div>`(of the well class) just before the second last `<% end %>`(of the `<% @posts.each do |post| %> loop`) it should fix the issue. So the last few lines should be

```
  <% else%>
    <p>You need to <%= link_to "sign in", new_user_session_path %> to comment</p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% else %>
No posts have been added!
<% end %>
```

Comment: This didn't work, but thanks anyway! I needed a parent div tag. Additionally, my indentation is fine, however most of it didn't display due to needing four spaces after each line, so I bumped those lines with less than four spaces up to meet the minimum criteria. What is the best way to go about this in future? Again, I appreciate your time.

Comment: For these kinda issues especially in a Rails app, I found using **`vi Editor`** very useful. Space issues can be easily rectified.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it could be a misplaced

```
<% end %>
```

or a missing

```
</div>
```

that is causing this behavior.
Proper indentation will point to where to close off actions or divs

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This was not the case - but I still appreciate any help. If I was missing an **end** anywhere, I would simply be getting an error.
My code is indented fine, however, most of it didn't display due to needing four spaces after each line, so I bumped those lines with less than four spaces up to meet the minimum criteria. What is the best way to go about this in future?

Comment: A missing <% end %> would throw an error. A misplaced <% end %> would cause loss of (or failure to lose) focus (aka scope), but would not show an error. When your <div> and </div> are on the same vertical plane, and your "dos" and <%ends %> are on the same vertical plane, it is easy to locate such errors.

Comment: Apologies, it was late when I replied to this. You're completely right though -- I somehow looked over the fact it said misplaced, and not missed. Thanks again, mate.